# Create small image gallery with same size image

Tags: html, css

I am creating a gallery with a number of images but the images are viewed in different size and they don't look attractive. I tried to change the height to 100px but all the images are overlapped. I want different sized images to be viewed as same size and also maintain its responsiveness.How can I make them responsive and of same size?

```js
/*
var importantStuff = window.open('', '_blank');
importantStuff.document.write('Loading preview...');
importantStuff.location.href = 'index.html';
*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Image Compression</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="1.png">
        <img src="1.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="2.png">
        <img src="2.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="3.png">
        <img src="3.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="4.png">
        <img src="4.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="5.png">
        <img src="5.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:5</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="6.png">
        <img src="6.png" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Image:6</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion would be to limit the img size with the a-tag around it. Check my changes for the a- and img-tag in my example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

div.gallery img {
  min-width: 100%;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {

  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Image Compression</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="1.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x150">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:1</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="2.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:2</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="3.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:3</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="4.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x300">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:4</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="5.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:5</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="6.png">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc"><h3>Image:6</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem with this solution is, that images are cut of, if the dimensions don't fit.